# Do I have pay Apple Developer fee to develop game that uses Game Center?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm trying to create a simple game that has Game Center's multiplayer. As I thought Sandbox would let me try developing such type of game without paying a developer fee. But now, as I found out that Game Center's Sandbox is no more a solution. ([Game Center: Life without a Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2417/_index.html))
So, do I have to pay to develop multiplayer game with Game Center?

Comment: Are you developing for iOS or for Mac? You have the iOS tag on your question so I would assume you're developing a game for iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Game Center is included in [the list of services which require a developer program](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/). This means that a developer program membership is required even if you don't want to submit your apps to the Store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to pay the developer fee to develop software for mac. Considering the resources Apple offers for developers, it's modest.

Comment: The OP has the iOS tag on (his?) question, so I think he's developing for iOS not Mac. For Mac you can develop apps without a developer license. You can't distribute via the app store, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, should have said iOS.  Using Game center would imply wanting to publish the game.

Answer (score 0):

If you interested of publishing your software on the appStore or MacStore you have to pay Apple Developers Fee every year.
But if you only interested in running you application on your device or the simulator you don't have to pay at all.

Comment: But if I want my app to use Game Center's multiplayer and I don't want to publish to App Store. Do I still have to pay or not?